# Release notes of Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: discussion, android-app

Where can I find the release notes of Stack Exchange's android app?  I tried searching but I couldn't find it.

In [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin), I could find only precise information, not very detailed.

I also checked ([Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/233367)) question, but it is not here.

Can someone direct me to the link, if not why don't we create a new question stating *"Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange Android App"*?

Answer (score 4):

We don't currently have any page displaying the recent changes for the android app.

The bullet points described on the Play Store are the most important changes, but if you want more detailed ones take a look at all [android-app questions tagged status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+status-completed?sort=newest).

Comment: Little hard to navigate to all those questions, but still it would be great if we have a place to track it something similar to this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/233367).